# How to perform cross check between to different length columns in dataframes and create an a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes,

df1:

```
pno | bno | report
1 | 12 | somereport2.pdf
11 | 12 | somereporter.pdf
12 | 12 | somereportf.pdf
11 | 12 | somereportwee.pdf
1 | 12 | somereport22.pdf
11 | 12 | somereport22.pdf
```

df2:

```
pno
11
12
```

I want to create a new df based on a column `pno` of df1 and df2. So df3:

```
pno | bno | report
11 | 12 | somereporter.pdf
12 | 12 | somereportf.pdf
11 | 12 | somereportwee.pdf
11 | 12 | somereport22.pdf
```

That is the new df will only have values that are in df2 `pno` column. I tried using `merge`function as

```
newdf = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on=["pno","pno"]
```

But it created some random shape with lot of missing values. I tried to do left join,

```
newdf = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="left", on=["pno","pno"]
```

But it kept all the values without cross checking.

Is there a way to crosscheck one column with another and only keep those values in new df?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use isin to filter and mask the rowms you want

```
df1[df1['pno'].isin(df2['pno'])]
```